# Unable to scrape specific ‘span’ tag from website by using python library ‘Beautiful soup’

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing a data analysis project and trying to grab data from the website 'turo.com'; Unable to scrape data from a specific 'span' tag under specific 'div' tag. Here are the codes:

```
from requests import get
url = "https://turo.com/en-us/search?country=US&defaultZoomLevel=13&delivery=false&deliveryLocationType=googlePlace&endDate=12%2F17%2F2019&endTime=10%3A00&international=true&isMapSearch=false&itemsPerPage=200&latitude=34.0929744&location=Alhambra%20High%20School%2C%20South%202nd%20Street%2C%20Alhambra%2C%20CA%2C%20USA&locationType=Address&longitude=-118.1284232&maximumDistanceInMiles=50&placeId=ChIJsZLFwSbFwoARDVnxkdATxS0&region=CA&sortType=RELEVANCE&startDate=12%2F14%2F2019&startTime=10%3A00"
response = get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

carName = html_soup.find(class_ = "vehicleCard-makeModel")
carYear = html_soup.find(class_ = "vehicleCard-year")
carTrip = html_soup.find(class_ = "vehicleRatingAndTrips-trips")
carAllStart = html_soup.find(class_ = "allStarHostBadge-icon")
#JoinTime = html_soup.find(class_ = "media-body hostDetailCard-info")

# carStart = html_soup.find(class_ = "starRating vehicleWithDetailsInfo-attribute vehicleWithDetailsInfo-attribute--starRating")
#print(carName.text, carYear.text)
#print(carTrip.text)# print(carStart.)
#print(carAllStart.text)
#print(JoinTime.div.text[: -14])

print(carName)
print(carYear)
print(carTrip)
print(carAllStart)
#print(JoinTime)
```

Here are the outcome:

```
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the actual HTML returned by requests? That's what matters.

Answer (score 0):

The class names you are using do not match those I see on the page when I load it up in my browser of choice. More importantly, the content is loaded dynamically, so there are no informational frames on the page as it is initially served up, so you cannot simply request the page and scrape the information; you must use a headless browser. Go ahead and inspect the page response to confirm. Best of luck.

Comment: thank you for your kindly replied; the 'span' tag is under <div class='vehicleCard-textWrapper'> / <div class='vehicleCard-makeModel'>

Comment: carTrip is under <span class="vehicleRatingAndTrips-trips">49 trips</span>, thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @Alan.Tan I can confirm what pkfm said. I just checked the HTML source, there is nothing for the tags you shared.

Comment: @Alan.Tan its possible the site is serving up different versions of itself depending on the headers sent with the request. This is not uncommon.

Comment: pkfm and Alexander écile ;  thank you your both very much for collecting me, properly the tags I posted before was corresponding with the pervious 'url' which I was looking for. but even I update the new tag it still print out 'none', I have been try for many times, so I will try your suggestiion to use headless browser. but would that be an issue if the page is javascript heavy website so I should use another library ??

Answer (score 0):

Data is retrieved dynamically from an API call you can find in the network tab when refreshing the page. Pass the appropriate params and header then handle the json response.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'referer': 'https://turo.com/en-us/search?country=US&defaultZoomLevel=13&delivery=false&deliveryLocationType=googlePlace&endDate=12/23/2019&endTime=11:00&international=true&isMapSearch=false&itemsPerPage=200&latitude=34.0929744&location=Alhambra High School, South 2nd Street, Alhambra, CA, USA&locationType=Address&longitude=-118.1284232&maximumDistanceInMiles=50&placeId=ChIJsZLFwSbFwoARDVnxkdATxS0&region=CA&sortType=RELEVANCE&startDate=12/23/2019&startTime=10:00',
}

params = (
    ('country', 'US'),
    ('defaultZoomLevel', '13'),
    ('delivery', 'false'),
    ('deliveryLocationType', 'googlePlace'),
    ('endDate', '12/23/2019'),
    ('endTime', '11:00'),
    ('international', 'true'),
    ('isMapSearch', 'false'),
    ('itemsPerPage', '200'),
    ('latitude', '34.0929744'),
    ('location', 'Alhambra High School, South 2nd Street, Alhambra, CA, USA'),
    ('locationType', 'Address'),
    ('longitude', '-118.1284232'),
    ('maximumDistanceInMiles', '50'),
    ('placeId', 'ChIJsZLFwSbFwoARDVnxkdATxS0'),
    ('region', 'CA'),
    ('sortType', 'RELEVANCE'),
    ('startDate', '12/23/2019'),
    ('startTime', '10:00'),
)

r = requests.get('https://turo.com/api/search', headers = headers, params=params)
data = r.json()
listings = data['list']

for listing in listings:
    car_name = ' '.join([listing['vehicle']['make'], listing['vehicle']['model']])
    car_year = listing['vehicle']['year']
    car_trip = listing['renterTripsTaken']
    car_allstar = listing['owner']['allStarHost']
    print([car_name, car_year, car_trip, car_allstar]), car_trip, car_allstar])
```

Comment: Nice work thank you very much; but why I can only retrieved 200 items even I change the itemsPerPage data in params and URL ?? How to apply the loop concept on Jason respond  in order to get more data ?

Comment: How do you know there is more data?

Comment: No matter how many times I changed 'time', 'maximumDistanceInMiles' and 'itemsPerPage', the outcome always show 200 items. How can I scrape the total cars listed in the specific area within specific miles ?

Comment: I would suggest consider accepting this answer and opening a new question. Explain in that question you want all items and make sure it is an example where one can prove there are more than 200 items. Explain that you have tried altering params within the query string to no avail - result is always 200 max (is this the case if you request < 200 ?).....